# segFault error on release apk logs for react native app

Tags: android, react-native, segmentation-fault, live-streaming

Release apk is failing with the segFault error when I try to access cameraview using react native nodemediaclient.

```
import { NodeCameraView } from "react-native-nodemediaclient";

    render() {

        return (
            <View style={styles.container}>

                {
          cameraPermission == 'authorized' && microphonePermission == 'authorized' &&

            <NodeCameraView
              style={styles.videoStream}
              ref={vb => {
                this.vb = vb;
              }}
              outputUrl={
                `rtmp://api-mux/app/${params.key}`
              }
              camera={{cameraId: 1, cameraFrontMirror: true}}
              audio={{bitrate: 32000, profile: 1, samplerate: 44100}}
              video={{
                preset: 4,
                bitrate: 400000,
                profile: 1,
                fps: 15,
                videoFrontMirror: false,
              }}
              autopreview={true}
              smoothSkinLevel = {1}
            />
```

Comment: Any solution to this? I am also getting a SIGSEGV - Segfault error in my React native app.

Comment: @instanceof is the segfault error happening while accessing came with nodemediaclient?